# returning multiple Mat from an OpenCV method

Tags: opencv, mat

In openCV code sapmles in it's document, I saw they simply pass the Mat as a refrence and fill it.
But I have a problem in my code. when i call TestMethod, it doese not fill them.

```
void TestMethod(Mat a, Mat b)
{
a = imread("img1.jpg");
b = imread("img2.jpg");

return;
}
```

Comment: try to use Mat &a , Mat &b  or use Mat* a , Mat* b  , one of them should work I don't have time to test it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be confused by how OpenCV uses typedefs to hide reference types. I would lookup how typedefs like `InputArray` are defined, you'll see they have an `&` in them to make them reference types. `cv::Mat` is not a typedef so you need to declare it as a reference in the function's argument list.

```
void TestMethod(Mat& a, Mat& b)
{
    a = imread("img1.jpg");
    b = imread("img2.jpg");

    return;
}
```

The way you have it written now, a and b are copies of the Mat variables you passed when you called the function. You are just overwriting copies that are deallocating when the function returns.